# how to configure service discovery in bluemix for microsrvices (written in java)

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, microservices, service-discovery

I have 5 microsrvices:

1. acmeair-mainapp (main service)
2. acmeair-as
3. acmeair-bs
4. acmeair-cs
5. acmeair-fs

Which application should I include in SD or how can these applications be configured?

I have followed the Bluemix documentation but things are not transparent with how to follow the steps. The Bluemix docs says to add some code to register a new service and it gives sample code for nodeJS, Python, and cURL, yet my application is written in java. Please help me proceed.

Answer (score 2):

By main service I assume that application is the one that needs to talk to the other 4.

Conceptually, what you will do in this case is have acmeair-as, acmeair-bs, acmeair-cs, acmeair-fs register with a unique name and url with service discovery.

acmeair-mainapp will then request the name of the microservice it needs to talk to and service discovery will return to you the URL of that microservice.

You can use this Java code I have as an [example](https://github.com/alohr51/Microservices-Orders/blob/master/src/com/ibm/ws/msdemo/service/disovery/ServiceDiscovery.java) to register a Java microservice with service discovery (which is what your 4 microservice apps should do) It additionally does the "heartbeat" needed to keep your application alive in SD's eyes.

You can also view the [Service Discovery API Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/129?&language=java). They provide Java samples for their requests there. These Docs can help you craft a request for your main application to use to get the URLs it needs from the other 4 microservices

Comment: first thanks a lot for quick reply but as I am a non developer(Infra Admin) so can i do that service discovery registration of my 4 services without making any code changes. and also as bluemix is having rich UI so can I make use of it without struggling in code changes.